# Filtering Dropdown value in jqgrid

Tags: filter, jqgrid

I hava a problem in the filter functionality for a column thats has dropdown values .Below is my code,

```
{
        name: 'statusFlag',
        width: 130,
        editable:true,
        edittype:'select',
        formatter : 'select',
        searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne']},
        editoptions:{value:{Y:'Active',N:'Inactive'}}
    }
```

If I perform search with 'y' I am seeing records with column value active, and If I perform search with 'n', I am seeing records with column value inactive. I want the same functionality to work when I enter active and inactive instead of y /n. How should i changed the code. Should i use formatOptions or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `stype: "select"` property and extend `searchoptions` with `value`:

```js
{
    name: 'statusFlag',
    width: 130,
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'select',
    formatter: 'select',
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;Y:Active;N:Inactive' } },
    editoptions: { value: 'Y:Active;N:Inactive' }
}
```

The usage of `:Any` part in `searchoptions.value` is recommended if you use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#installation). If you use only searching dialog then you can remove the value and just use the same `value` like in `editoptions`.

Comment: :I have a doubt, If the values are not static, let say i get the dropdown as dynamic, In that case how will i have the values populated

Comment: Oleg: Is it possible to use text search box and still get the result working . Instead of advance search option like dropdown, cant we use the direct search box and search for value..

Comment: @user2375298: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. What is "text search box"? Input filed? In the case the user have to type the exact values like `Y` for "Active" and `N` for "Inactive".